# Update graph to add today's data on button click

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a spreadsheet which gives me new numerical data for every business day when I F9.

I want to use VBA code to update a graph, every time I click a command button, for every day that passes, while storing previous data.

For example, say today is Dec. 20, the first day of using the code. I want it to generate the point the sheet outputs on a line graph from -1 - 1 for Dec 20.
On Dec 21, once I hit the command button, it saves the old data on the line graph for Dec. 20 (without erasing it), and adds a new point for Dec. 21 (now connecting them - and seeing a relationship between today and yesterday's data).
On Dec. 22, once I hit the command button, it saves the points for Dec. 20 & 21, and continues to add the new data for the line graph.

What I have outputs today's graph. I need it to save today's data as one point on the x axis (as today's date representing the x variable), and then for the next day, update the chart by adding the new data for that day as a new x variable (represented by the next day's date).

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("RV")
For Row = 1 To 20
    Dim my_cell
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("RV").Range("H14:P15") 'selects daily Realized Vol ratios for FV, TY & US

    For Each my_cell In rng
        If my_cell <> "" Then

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'RV'!$H$14:$P$15")
            ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
            ActiveSheet.Activate
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='RV'!$H$14:$P$14"
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Ratios Progress"""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Progress"""
            ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
            ActiveSheet.Activate
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

        Else
            Exit For ' Blank cell found, exiting
        End If
    Next
 
Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to keep all the stored points in a table.
Next just write a quick little macro to store the new points on the table:

```
Sub UpdateGraph()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Sheet1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheet1.Range("F" & LastRow + 1 & ":H" & LastRow + 1).Value = _
        Sheet1.Range("C4:D4").Value
        
    ' To Create new mock data for your viewing enjoyment.
    ' You can omit this. 
    Call CreateNewMockDateData
    
End Sub
```

Every day, you can press your command button and the new data will be added to your graph.

[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]
[image: IMG3]
[image: IMG4]

No reason this has to be all on the same sheet, make your table on a hidden sheet.

Look at that, datapoint2 did finally reclaim the crown!

[image: IMG5]

Comment: Thank you so much this is one of the most in depth answers I could have asked for. You going through each of the steps and also posting the images really helped understand how to alter the code for my sheet as well. Thanks again